# How do political groups address willful ignorance to their causes by people?

Tags: citizen-activism

One example would be drug laws. If advocates of drug law reform present arguments in favor of lenient drug legislation, the target audience of those advocates may choose to ignore them because the issue does not affect them directly, even though they have the power to bring about change. In this situation, what do advocates usually do?

Comment: Who exactly is the "target audience" in this scenario? Politicians? Or apathetic citizens? Also, can we assume you are talking about a representative democracy here?

Comment: This question could definitely use some rewording, particular with regard to use of they, them, and their. I'm leery of doing so as my rewording may completely shift the intent of the original poster.

Comment: Drug laws are perhaps not the best choice regarding willful ignorance. The politicians who are adamantly opposed to legalizing some drugs or making drug laws more lenient can cite plenty of literature that shows that keeping drugs illegal is the better option. Opinions and scientific research are quite divided on this issue. A better choice might be climate change. The scientific research is pretty much unanimous here: It's real, it's caused by us, and things will get bad if nothing is done. That includes internal research performed by petrochemical companies, which they hid for a long time.

Comment: If you look at history: they eventually either do nothing or stage a violent revolution. If you're writing a story you get to choose which one.

Comment: This might be too broad, there are so many political groups all over the world. Maybe the question wants the narrow down the scope somewhat liked geographically, topically, ...

Comment: I wonder what kind of answers the question expects? A trivial answer might be that some groups double down and others give up while completely others just go on as if there was nothing changed. Would this be a satisfying answer? Or how could it be answered better.

Comment: The scenario you describe isn't "willful ignorance". You are describing a situation where someone may understand the problem but chooses to do nothing about it. This can be for many motives, including "there are more important things to do". Wilful ignorance is when someone chooses not to find out about an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of the term 'willful ignorance' may be true in an objective sense, but objective truth can be hard to determine. You have two sides, and one side has no interest in listening to the arguments of the other side. (Or perhaps not any more, because they listened once and were not convinced?)

Take the debate about mask mandates. There are those who think that in case of some pandemics, *everybody* needs to wear a mask in public to protect *everybody else*. There are those who think that in a free society, every responsible citizen needs to *make a determination* when when to wear a mask, and when to engage in economic activity without a mask. And there are those who think that it is all *fake news*. There are heated arguments about which groups are ignorant, willful or not.

So what can be done?

- Disrupt normal life through protests and civil disobedience.
  Depending on the state they live in, this could bring severe consequences, but it can also bring [visibility](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-64321652). The people who do not share the protesters' views may not be swayed, but the situation will make the evening news.
- Debate the other side in news programs, etc.
  There are media formats where representatives of different viewpoints throw talking points at each other, with the host/referee making sure that they don't come to blows. When 95% of a field are 'willfully ignorant,' and 5% are 'aware,' such a format might make it look as if it was 50-50. That can backfire, of course, when there are just a few percent of holdouts in a field of science.
- Find influencers.
  Convince music stars and other celebrities to endorse the cause. They have lots of media followers.

Comment: For an example of "severe consequences", see https://www.nytimes.com/live/2022/02/09/world/canada-trucker-protest

Comment: Re: *There are those who think that in case of some pandemics, everybody needs to wear a mask in public to protect everybody else* - I'd note that many agreed that mandatory masking is necessary in *some* pandemics, but COVID wasn't severe enough to justify it.

Comment: Since the "willfully ignorant" to which the OP is referring appear to be lawmakers (but the question is not quite clear on this), a fourth alternative would be for the advocates to use their 1st amendment rights (*Citizens United v. FEC*) to get those lawmakers voted out of office. Make nasty and perhaps even misleading advertisements, etc.

Comment: @JonathanReez, which would be the second group I picked as my example. I have considerably more sympathy for those than for the third group. But I consider mask mandates to be relatively low impact on the population, compared to the economic closures of the last years.

Comment: what about countries which have arbitrary propaganda laws ? which restrict what topics can be discussed. for example blasphemy laws.

Comment: @WhyDenounce, the first bullet point means *breaking laws and publicly taking the consequences,* in the hope that the public finds that unfair.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest model is to gather your political base and then form coalitions with other parties, who are interested in other causes but are not hostile to yours. Then you can pool your votes. You can also pick up other causes to which you were ignorant previously and gather more audience.

Answer (score 1):

One of the central purposes of activism is exactly to make people aware of their cause who are not personally affected by it.

One of the main things that activists do for that purpose is to protest in public spaces. Public spaces are visited by a lot of people; some people may be inconvenienced by e.g. roads being blocked. Recent examples in many (certainly many Western) countries are the BLM protests and the climate protests. They made a lot of people who were doing other things in public spaces aware of their respective causes and, no doubt, had lots of effect.

Protests also cause journalists to report on those protests. Journalists are typically quite eager for a good story, and large protests are definitely a good story. For example, [here (start at 6:52) you can watch a video of an activist, Meir Kahane](https://youtu.be/oLnf9PR55LA?t=412), explaining some details about how to get the attention of journalists. (You can go back to 2:10 in the same video for some extra details which sound a lot less peaceful.)

Note that it is not always 100% obvious that it was the activism, and not something else, that ended up causing actual change to happen. Think of same-sex marriage, which became a lot more popular very quickly in recent decades even though activist movements for it had existed for much longer. I like the hypothesis expressed in [this blog comment](https://slatestarcodex.com/2019/02/22/rip-culture-war-thread/#comment-723596) which states that the purpose of activism is only to get people to realize that certain questions exist to be asked at all.

(Note: I am not expressing any substantive opinion on any of the examples of activism in this post. They are meant to serve as examples of mechanisms of activism.)